# Rebol text fields - checking values and changing colors

Tags: rebol

In the following prototype test code, I'm trying to create a comparison system that compares two fields, and colors them depending on whether they are equal or not.

```
comparecolors: [
    either answer-user/text = answer-correct/text [
        answer-user/font/color: green
        answer-correct/font/color: green
        show answer-user
        show answer-correct
    ][
        answer-user/font/color: red
        answer-correct/font/color: black
        show answer-user
        show answer-correct
    ]
]

view layout [
    answer: field [
        answer-user/text: copy answer/text
        do comparecolors
        show answer
        focus answer
        show answer-user
    ]
    label "Compare"
    answer-user: info
    answer-correct: info
    across
    text-list "Hello" "Goodbye" "Boy" "Girl" "Soldier" [
        answer-correct/text: copy value
        do comparecolors
        show answer-correct
    ]
]
```

Some problems I am having:

- The green color is affecting all the fields instead of just the ones I am specifying.
- The red color is not working when the two fields are not equal.
- The system does not check for none! value (I know it is not written so in the above code, but I tried some ways that didn't work, so I don't really know how to go about it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see multiple fields affected when you change the attribute of only one, it means that VID has made an optimization so that all those fields are sharing the same data structure, and in this the same font structure.  So, we need to force VID to allocate a new font structure like this:

```
change-colors: func [ user [object!] correct [object!]
    /local u c
 ][
    set [ u c ]  
    either user/text = correct/text [
        [ green green ]
    ][
         [ red black ]
    ]
    user/font/color: get u
    correct/font/color: get c
    show [ user correct ]   
]

view layout [
    answer: field [
        answer-user/text: copy answer/text
        change-colors answer-user answer-correct
        focus answer
    ] font-color black
    label "Compare"
    answer-user: info  font-color black
    answer-correct: info  font-color black
    across
    text-list "Hello" "Goodbye" "Boy" "Girl" "Soldier" [
        answer-correct/text: copy value
        change-colors answer-user answer-correct
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Works splendidly, as always :)
Reading your code... it's like you write in Rebol with a different language. It's elegant in it's own way (I mean, mainly what catches my eye are the padded spaces inside brackets, but they make it seem so different).
And I never knew **set** could be used like that, or even that it existed as a word.
Could you explain the significance of [object!] in there?

Comment: About [object!], when you use it like above change-colors function accepts only object! values if you give any other type when calling the function (accidently for ex.) you get much more understandable error message like "** Script Error: change-colors expected correct argument of type: object" otherwise "** Script Error: Invalid path value: text". Try calling change-colors with a string! value and see the result with and without [object!] in definition.

Comment: It's probably a matter of taste to include spaces immediately adjacent to brackets.  Some people don't like them :)